# How to complete/fix additive persistence algorithm without converting to string?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, math, while-loop

Trying to code additive persistence algorithm.
AP is when you have a number and you keep adding its digits until you are left with a single digit number. E.g. 9991 = 9+9+9+1 = 28, and 2+8=10, 1+0=1. So, the additive persistence for 9991 is 3. It took 3 additions to reduce the number to a single digit number.

I have coded the problem but it keeps incrementing the counter. Looks correct to me but cant get it to work lol.

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ui;
    int b;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    ui = reader.nextInt();

    do {
        do {
            b = ui % 10;
            ui = ui / 10;
            sum += b;

        } while (ui != 0);

        ui = sum;
        count++;

        //System.out.print(b);
        //System.out.print(sum);
        //System.out.print(ui);

    } while (ui > 10);

    System.out.print(count+1);
}
```

Comment: Did you run the program through debugger in your IDE?

Comment: I dont really know how to use the debugger. It displays some error with my IP? But thank you for bringing the debugger to my attention. Ill learn to use it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `sum` on every run, otherwise you're assigning `ui` to it ad it's more than 10 until overflow. Here is a correct version:

```
do {
    sum = 0;
    do {
        b = ui % 10;
        ui = ui / 10;
        sum += b;

    } while (ui > 9);
    sum += ui;

    ui = sum;
    count++;

} while (ui > 9);

System.out.print(count);
```

Comment: I tried the number 1654 and the answer came out to be 3,not 2. Could you explain why? The program seems to work with various other numbers i tried. Also, its not working with 1*10^n, and 9993.

Comment: Right, you need to print `count`, not `count + 1`

Comment: if i do that, then 9992 doesnt work. 9992 > 9+9+9+2 = 29 > 2+9=11 > 1+1=2. It takes 3 steps but the program outputs 2.

Comment: Ach, we have forgotten about one more thing: `sum += ui` after the inner loop, can you try it now?